# Running code before object-cache.php runs

Tags: php, cache, plugin-w3-total-cache, apc

I want to polyfill some functions before `object-cache.php` runs. I have PHP7 and APCu installed. However, W3 Total Cache is using `apc_*` functions, not `apcu_*` functions. W3 Total Cache's object cache runs using `object-cache.php`, which is loaded before any plugins run.

How can I run custom code before W3 Total Cache runs without modifying WordPress core? I also can't use PHP's `auto_prepend_file` because WordFence is using it.

Here is the code I want to run:

```
if (function_exists('apcu_add') && !function_exists('apc_add')) {
    function apc_add() {
        return call_user_func_array('apcu_add', func_get_args());
    }

    function apc_cache_info() {
        return call_user_func_array('apcu_cache_info', func_get_args());
    }

    function apc_cas() {
        return call_user_func_array('apcu_cas', func_get_args());
    }

    ...
}
```

I might just paste it into `wp-config.php`.

Comment: not 100% sure for this case but `/wp-content/mu-plugins/` directory is typically best for things like this.

Comment: In `wp-settings.php`, the object cache is initialized before multisite is initialized.

Comment: I suppose you could put it in `advanced-cache.php` but that may be overwritten by w3c anyway, so I guess your best bet is probably `wp-config.php` after all.